# httpClient.get call is returning 404 Not Found Error

Tags: http

I attempt to get a list of products from localhost:4200 using the following code...

In one file:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} 
getProducts(query: string): Observable<Product[]> { return this.http.get<Product[]>('/api/product'); }
```

In another file I call the above `getProducts()`, like this:

```
this.products$ = this.productService.getProducts( "" );
```

The error is this:

> status 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "localhost:4200/api/product".

I don't know how to query the structure of a localhost site, so I am rather stuck as to how to understand and fix this "Not Found" problem.

Also, there was also a similar error just before this one:

> zone-evergreen.js:2952 GET http://localhost:4200/api/product 404 (Not Found)

Can you help me out?

Comment: Do you know if you have a service running on localhost:4200? This request is assuming you have something running there. The 404 suggests either the service doesn't support the endpoint you are trying to request from or, you don't have anything running there.

Comment: I think I have something running there, prompted by ng serve.  When I run ng serve, with nothing else going on, followed by a compiled successful message, followed by my "localhost: 4200" entry in the address bar, the browser attempts to load my site.  In fact it partially succeeds but it doesn't load the products requested by my getProducts() call.

Comment: Do you have an api setup on /api? What happens when you go to http://localhost:4200/api?

Comment: When I go to localhost:4200/api from my browser, the results are the same as if I had gone from localhost:4200.  The code compiles cleanly buy I get the familiar 404 error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This is just a guess so bear with me. It seems like you have a setup that is using /api as a proxy in your Angular configuration, however, you don't have anything setup that /api is proxying to and thus giving you the 404. For this to work you would need a backend service setup and look into the proxy settings to get it configured properly.

Checkout [this](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server). It is common to use proxying to fetch your api on the same url and port so you don't have CORS issues.